# What it is the logic of date parsing in different formats in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm trying to understand how javascript's `Date` api acts when parsing the date and I cant justify the way javascript parse same dates but different formats into different dates.

```js
const date1 = new Date('2020-05-13');
const date2 = new Date('2020-12-28');

const date1Reversed = new Date('05-13-2020');
const date2Reversed = new Date('05-28-2020');

console.group('Date Format: YYYY-MM-DD')
console.log(date1);
console.log(date2);
console.groupEnd();

console.group('Date Format: MM-DD-YYYY')
console.log(date1Reversed);
console.log(date2Reversed);
console.groupEnd();
```

Above code gives below output

```
Date Format: YYYY-MM-DD
  2020-05-13T00:00:00.000Z
  2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z
Date Format: MM-DD-YYYY
  2020-05-12T21:00:00.000Z
  2020-05-27T21:00:00.000Z
```

Dates are identical but the `mm-dd-yyyy` date parsed into GMT-3, what is the logic behind this ?

Comment: FWIW, my browser gives `null` for the last two… TL;DR: if the format is *non-standard*, there's no specific answer you can expect (by definition), and every browser will fail in different ways.

Comment: Is GMT+03:00 your current computer's time zone?

Comment: I think that has something to do with timezones. For you the second batch is 3h behind, on my browser its just 2. Cant say what the problem is exactly though.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes it is

Comment: You have a good overview at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string).

Comment: Momentjs is a good tool to deal with dates: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you for the reference.

Comment: The logic is that the TC39 decided that YYYY-MM-DD format dates should be parsed as UTC whereas common use and ISO 8601 parse them as local following the convention that dates and date/times without an offset are local.